# Почему PhpStorm показывает, что в коде ошибка, хотя в нем нет ошибки?

Tags: php, phpstorm, kohana

Есть вот такой фрагмент кода:

```
try {
    if (!class_exists($prefix . $controller)) {
        throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404, 'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.', array(':uri' => $request->uri())
        )->request($request);
    }

  // Load the controller using reflection
  $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix . $controller);

  if ($class->isAbstract()) {
    throw new Kohana_Exception(
    'Cannot create instances of abstract :controller', array(':controller' => $prefix . $controller)
    );
  }

  // Create a new instance of the controller
  $controller = $class->newInstance($request, $response);

  // Run the controller's execute() method
  $response = $class->getMethod('execute')->invoke($controller);

  if (!$response instanceof Response) {
    // Controller failed to return a Response.
    throw new Kohana_Exception('Controller failed to return a Response');
  }
} catch (HTTP_Exception $e) {
  // Get the response via the Exception
  $response = $e->get_response();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Generate an appropriate Response object
  $response = Kohana_Exception::_handler($e);
}
```

PhpStorm помечает try ошибочным:

```
The thrown object must be an instance of the Exception or Throwable
```

Вот наследование:

```
HTTP_Exception - Kohana_HTTP_Exception - Kohana_Exception - Kohana_Kohana_Exception - Exception
```

Вот код request:

```
public function request(Request $request = NULL) {
    if ($request === NULL)
      return $this->_request;

    $this->_request = $request;

    return $this;
}
```

Это код фреймворка Kohana. Почему PhpStorm показывает, что в коде ошибка? Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Я исправил такое с помощью try catch

Comment: Можете написать код?

Comment: Потом, с компьютера. Но все просто. У вас есть try, добавьте к нему catch.

Comment: catch есть, я просто привел фрагмент кода без него. поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел на компьютере. Скопировал ваш пример, объявил пустые классы с указанным наследованием - ошибка пропала. У вас где-то синтаксис или опечатка.

Вот минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

```
<?php

class Kohana_Exception extends Kohana_Kohana_Exception {

}

class Kohana_Kohana_Exception extends Exception {

}

try {
    throw new Kohana_Exception(
        'Cannot create instances of abstract :controller', array( ':controller' => $prefix . 'controller' )
    );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    die();
}
```

К этому коду у phpStorm одна претензия - два класса в одном файле. Других проблем нет.